I need to see base imagery, not rasterized or smoothed or transformed
Looking at ESRI tile imagery in QGIS, I am imagining the underlying imagery is pixelized, but that these pixels are rasterized, blended or transformed into a basic blur when zoomed in.  I would prefer to see the pixels as they appear in the digital imagery, if that isn't being changed by the service. Is there a way in QGIS to simply turn of the transform, so that the original imagery appears pixelated when zoomed in?
I can save images to geoTIFFs and get what I am looking for, but seeing the pixels (that is, the resolution) of the raw imagery is what I am looking for.  The images below show the kind of thing I'm struggling with.  The first image, a saved TIFF, shows the pixelation clearly. The 2nd just blends, blurs and makes them look nicer, which is helpful, but not if it can't be turned off for a look at the original.  Is the server doing this, or QGIS?



The resampling method and oversampling level are can be selected in the raster settings. Nearest neighbour without oversampling will keep the pixels as original. Naturally the project CRS must be the same than the layer CRS for avoiding resampling due to re-projection.

With these settings a close zoom of a raster map looks exactly the same in QGIS and in GIMP.


Thanks a-million! but this setting does not get to what I need.  I am using ESRi's XYZ (and other tile servers).  I'll add detail to the original question.

I do not know if tiles are scaled and rendered though a different path than for example local TIFFs. Open the debugging tools for seeing the http requests. Download a few tiles manually from the service and compare with what you see in QGIS.
